# Regex to match lines that contain at least a certain ratio of numbers:letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for a regex that will match lines that are more than 25% numbers (0-9).

When it comes to regex, I am absolutely lost. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. My usual strategy for solving regex problems is google it.

Alternatively if this cannot be done in regex, is there a way to do it in Notepad++ or another tool?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you can do with a regexp, they can't count and compare.

Comment: @yuuu  can you share with us a simple of that data? May be possible

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah There is a very wide variety of data, including dates, prices, weights, distances, long lines (255+ chars), and short lines (5 chars). A general solution would be good but even one that works for some cases would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : Sadly it's not possible to do that.

Long answer : it's possible but only for very short line and asumming all line are the same lenght.

for example, with a 4 characters line you can do :

```
(^[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$)|(^\d\d\d\d$)
```

I'm not aware of any tool that can do what you want but it's certainly possible to code a short python script to do that.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers = sum(c.isdigit() for c in line)
        letters = sum(c.isalpha() for c in line)
        if numbers/letters > 0.25:
            #do something
```